# How to make a new array with some of an existing array elements in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to make a new array which contains some of elements from the first array which are greater than 5. (n is the size of the first array)

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] > 5)
    {
        new_array[i] = numbers[i];
        printf("%d ", new_array[i]);
    }
}
```

If I do it like this it works perfectly and prints a new array with only those elements that are greater than 5.
But if I write it like this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] > 5)
    {
        new_array[i] = numbers[i];
    }
}
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", new_array[i]);
}
```

It doesn't work. It prints an array of n numbers and on the locations where >5 numbers were in the original array there are these numbers but on other locations there are weird numbers. How can I fix this? I want to find the minimum number in the new array and print it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the same index into both the old and new array.  You need to keep a separate counter for each.

Also, arrays in C are zero based so you should count from 0 to n-1 instead of 1 to n.

```
int m = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] > 5)
    {
        new_array[m] = numbers[i];
        m++;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", new_array[i]);
}
```

Comment: OH! you are right!! I didn't pay attention to it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have been trying to fix it for really long time! It's funny there was such a tiny mistake

Comment: @OrangeBike Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the other locations have never been initialized, so could be literally anything.

You can either initialize the array beforehand or keep a separate index for your new array.  For instance int j = 0;  Then every time you assign to new_array increment j.  This way new_array will only have the elements > 5, and you will know how many elements it holds.